# describe catching a cold as "easy"

Tags: word-meaning, idiomatic-language

Is it natural to describe catching a cold as easy?

> It is easy to catch a cold if you are in close contact with other cold sufferers.

Comment: Why would you think it is not natural?

Comment: *You could easily die if you picnic on the motorway hard shoulder.* Not everything that's ***easy*** is necessarily ***deliberate***.

Comment: I have no problem with "easily" in your sentence. I'm asking about the adjective "easy."

Comment: @Apollyon If you can clarify what it is you're concerned about, we might be able to answer. In FumbleFingers' example, "easily" is an adverb modifying "die." In your example, it's an adjective modifying the infinitive "to catch." https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/a-common-form-be-adjective-infinitive-/5284365.html

Comment: @AndyBonner Someone says the adjective version  sounds odd because it makes catching a cold sound like a task that would be easy to accomplish. No one wants to catch a cold.

Comment: an easy to accomplish task isn't necessarily a desirable one.